# How to match list and pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a list called `myList = []`. 
I want to compare the ones in the zero index of this list with the ["numbers"] arm of the dataframe pd. I want to separate those that are not the same as the list.

For example:

```
myList=["20","30","40","31","41"]
pd["numbers"] = ["20","30","40","41","31",**"50"**]
```

Comment: `df[~df['numbers'].isin(myList)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `set`

**Ex:**

```
myList=["20","30","40","31","41"]
df = pd.DataFrame({"numbers": ["20","30","40","41","31","50"]})
print(set(df['numbers']) - set(myList))
# --> {'50'}
```